# how can i copy table and data from one database to another using oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, copy, export

I'm using Oracle PL/SQL developer. I have two databases live and dummy.

I have been using the dummy database for development and now i need to add all the new tables and data into the live database without effecting the data currently stored in it.

I also need to copy over all the new sequences and triggers.

I've tried exporting a table but had no luck and using the SQL view i only get the SQL for the creation of the data and not the data it contains.

I also found this SQL code

```
COPY FROM test@DUMMY - CREATE test -USING SELECT * FROM test;
```

But it asks me for a name and password of which I dont know and then fails after 3 attempts. It then goes on to say there is a syntax error as well.

I'm still fairly new to using Oracle and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think [this](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/oracle-data-pump-10g.php) should solve your problem. I don't know much about it but just thought this might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using [datapump](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/oracle-data-pump-10g.php).

or if you want to copy from schema to schema

```
create table shecma2.old_table 
as 
select * from schema1.old_table
```

or using oracle sql developer - [here](http://st-curriculum.oracle.com/obe/db/11g/r2/prod/appdev/sqldev/sqldev_adv/sqldev_adv_otn.htm) is link.

Comment: hmmm  it says table or view does not exist! when i know it does.

Comment: yes 100% however if i change the full stop to an @ on the select query as this link suggests(http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_displaying_tables_schema_database_link.htm) i get an error regarding the connection description for remote database so i think it might be a permissions issue

Comment: Are you talking about datapump?

Comment: well I'm not entirely sure what datapump is but I'm just on about copying the table and its contents to a different database

Comment: I added a link how to copy table using `oracle sql developer`.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
CREATE TABLE NEWTABLE AS SELECT * FROM OLDTABLE;
```